# getting real-time data of IoT core and sending it to the frontend application

Tags: amazon-web-services

Are there any other cost-effective services in aws than AWS API WebSocket to retrieve data from AWS IoT Core and send it to a frontend application in real-time?

I have implemented it using AWS WebSocket API Gateway, but I want to ensure that there are no other cost-effective services available in aws for obtaining real-time data from IoT Core and communicating with the frontend application.